# IIS Express messing with HTTP Status on exception

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-express

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 REST API app. I want to be able to run it as a windows service as well as on IIS so I have created a startup project for each and they use a shared Core library for the "guts" of the app. I am using CORS which I think may be coming into play.

The Service project runs normally under dotnet.exe from visual studio and the IIS project runs using IIS Express from visual studio. Their startup code differs very little and is at the end of this post.

Like most rest API's, I want to rely on Http status codes to convey information. On one endpoint, I want to use the RequestSizeLimitAttribute to return a 413 status if the request exceeds a certain limit.

The windows service project behaves correctly, returning the correct status codes to the client. But when I run as IIS Express, the client first sends an OPTIONS request and gets a 204 back (as expected), but then the response after that is always a 502-Bad Gateway.

Does IIS mess with things if an exception happens because of the RequestSizeLimitAttribute?

```
//IIS Express Project Startup Code
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IConfiguration config => new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

AND

```
 //Windows Service startup code
 public static IConfiguration config => new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     RunWebHost(args, logger);
 }

 public static void RunWebHost(string[] args)
 {
     var isService = true;

     if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"))
     {
         isService = false;
     }

     var pathToContentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

     if (isService)
     {
        var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
     }

     var webHostArgs = args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray();

     var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(webHostArgs)
            .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        if (isService)
        {
            host.RunAsService();
        }
        else
        {
            host.Run();
        }
 }
```

Comment: The 502 is from IIS Express, not the ASP.NET Core app. IIS Express is acting as a proxy between you and your app. When it doesn't get a proper response from your app, it returns a 502. Look here for details on how to troubleshoot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#app-startup-errors

Comment: You can also add this to the `aspNetCore` tag in your web.config to get more detailed error messages: `stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\path\to\whatever.txt"`

Comment: What's the sub status code of that 502? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 The more you dig into the error itself, the IIS Express/IIS setting would be obvious.

Comment: Its a 502.3. Saying that the app likely didn't return a valid set of http headers